# Perl: Reversing each word in a file

Tags: perl, reverse

I'm trying to write a script to reverse each word in a file in each lines

- Before:   `line1 asdasdfff`
- After:    `1enil fffdsadsa`

Using:

```
@lines = split(/\s+/, reverse($old));
```

Where's the bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a substitution with an evaluation:

```
s/(\S+)/reverse $1/ge for @lines;
```

This will capture all consecutive non-whitespace and replace them with the reversed version, in place. Example input/output:

```
I'm a little teapot short and stout
m'I a elttil topaet trohs dna tuots    

foobar qwerty aboo
raboof ytrewq ooba
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to reverse each word *in place*, then reversing the whole line and then splitting it is the issue. Because reversing the whole line changes the order of the words. So you either want:

```
my @lines = reverse split(/\s+/, reverse($old));
```

OR:

```
my @lines = map { reverse; } split /\s+/, $old;
```

The first one just simply reverses the list, the second one keeps the words in order and reverses each. According to how I worded the requirement, the second one looks more like what you want to do. Leaves the words in place and then reverses each word. (That's the thing about map-grep chains is that they are read right to left, proceeding toward the assignment, if you will.)

---

So, you want to reverse the lines. Such a case is not clear from your expected output (containing only one line.) In the case that `$old` is a *file handle* it is unsuitable as an argument to `reverse`. You have to use the "diamond operator" `<$var>`:

```
reverse( <$old> );
```

sucks all the records/lines into memory and outputs the reversed array. If you pass this to `split`, there are problems. You'll only be splitting the *text representation* of size of the array. As there are no spaces in a number it will consist of an array containing the size of the array. So you want to split *each* line...

```
map { [ split /\s+/ ] } reverse( <$old> );
```

I put them in an array so you don't just reverse the whole file and each line-array stays together as a unit. And then you need to reverse each word so split.

```
map { map { reverse; } split /\s+/ } reverse( <$old> );
```

Of course, you're going to have record separators in there, so you have to account for those. You could just put a `chomp` at the beginning of the outer `map`.

```
map { chomp; map { reverse; } split /\s+/ } reverse( <$old> );
```

And you might want to append the record separator to the end of each group, so you need to bundle the list of each word:

```
print map { chomp; (( map { reverse; } split /\s+/ ), $\ || $/ ) } reverse( <$old> );
```

So we had to isolate the `map` expression and then add the currently defined output record separator--or if not defined, input record separator to each split-and-reversed line.

Comment: why do i get >848df3x0<BOLG text in a new file?

Comment: @Rocker: Because $old is a file handle, not the content of a file.

Comment: @Rocker, if `$old` is a file handle, and your first order of business was to reverse the lines, then you want `reverse( <$old> )` . `<$old>` says "read the next record or all the records in a list".